# An easy way to delete a file in Rhythmbox play queue

Tags: 10.10, rhythmbox, music

When I listen music, I want to delete a file if the music in play queue is not good to me.
But there is only '*remove from play list*'. This is not what I want. I want to delete the file.
Clicking property, and check it's location. Then open file explorer, and delete the file. This is what I'm doing for the deletion. It makes me crazy.

Is there an easy way to delete a file in Rhythmbox play queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not. From the play queue you can only remove the file from the queue since it is a temporary list of the songs you have chosen to listen. The real list of songs is in the Music Option[image: Rhythmbox]

in this picture you see the Music section to the left. In the list below is where you can delete files. Right click on them and Move to trash for example. That will remove it. But to not have from the queue and remove you need to remove it from Queue and the delete like i said from the Music section.

Comment: I have never used Music section. I just drag files(and folder) to Play Queue even if the files are more 1000. Then shuffle the queue and listening.

Answer (score 1):

By the way you ask your question, can I assume that the song you want to remove is the one *currently playing*? If that is the case, then you can press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> which makes the interface jump to the currently playing song. From there, moving to trash is a right-click away.

Comment: > you can press CTRL+J which makes the interface jump to the currently playing song. From there, moving to trash is a right-click away. That is not entirely true (at least not in version 2.96) : This will actually open the queue section, not the music section, so back to the beginning. Even if I don't like to mix environments, I guess I will have to return to Amarok, like the poster of this topic did.

Comment: @glatapoui Since my answer was given over 2 years ago, I can imagine it might be outdated by now. It definitely worked back then though :)

Answer (score 1):

There is an extension which is devoted for this.

[Rhythmbox song deleter](http://alexshulzhenko.ru/rhythmbox-delete-current-song)

I have written it to solve this problem when  I didn't found anything that could solve this problem.

This is how it works:
[image]

You press a key and it shows you messagebox that song was trashed.

Answer (score 0):

Fave a look here, it's exactly what you're looking for. It even has configurable keyboard shortcuts:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/rhythmboxdelete/